# Why do we pick $\epsilon=1$ when trying to prove that every convergent sequence is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis

So I'm looking to the proof for the theorem "every convergent sequence is bounded". I was studying from both Lima's book and Rudin's book. In their proofs, both use $\epsilon=1 $. The proof is:

Suppose $||a_k||\rightarrow L$. Put $\epsilon=1$. Then, there exists an integer $n>N$ such that 
$$
||a_k-L||<1
$$
We know that $||a_k-L||\geq ||a_k||-||L|| $. Therefore,
$$
||a_k||\leq 1+||L||
$$
For all $n>N$. Now,consider
$$
r=max\{||a_1||,\dots,||a_N||\}
$$
Then, for $k\in \{1,\dots,N\}$ $r\geq ||a_k||$. Finally, it follows that if we pick $r'=max\{1+||L||,r\}$ we have $||a_k||\leq r'$.

So, there it comes the doubt: why do they pick  $\epsilon=1$. Aren't we supposed to prove for any $\epsilon$?

Comment: The denfinition of "convergent" says that something works for any $\epsilon > 0$.  So in particular it works for $\epsilon=1$.  And according to the proof you qoted, we get the conclusion we want from that.  So it is enough.  In fact, I could also prove it by choosing some other $\epsilon > 0$.  Say $\epsilon = 37$.

Comment: We already *know* that the definition of convergence of $a_k$ works for every $\epsilon>0$.  *Since* it works for every $\epsilon$ it works in particular for $\epsilon=1$.  There is nothing special about picking $\epsilon=1$ other than the fact that we like the number $1$.  It is convenient to do arithmetic with, it is simple, and we know that it is finite.  We also know that there can only be finitely many $k$ for which $\|a_k-L\|\geq 1$ which is the main observation in the proof.

Comment: We are proving that the sequence is bounded - we are not proving anything "for any $\epsilon$". The reason why we can pick $\epsilon=1$ is because by definition, for every $\epsilon >0,$ there exists... so that this property still holds when we pick $\epsilon=1$. The choice of $1$ is actually completely arbitrary here, and we could have picked $\epsilon=2, \pi, 9801$, or even $0.00000001$ - as long as we pick some positive constant the property of convergence can be used to proceed with the proof

Comment: A completely arbitrary choice, though its quite a simple number to write down: one strike of the chalk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why do they pick $\epsilon=1$. Aren't we supposed to prove for any $\epsilon$?

Prove what?  If we want to *show* that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$ exists, then yes, something needs to be shown true for every $\epsilon > 0$.

In this case, though, we are *given* that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$ exists.  So we can use the “for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists ...” property to our advantage.

As for “why set $\epsilon = 1$?”, try a different $\epsilon$ and you will see that the proof still works. You'll still be able to show that the sequence is bounded.  It's just a matter of style which positive number is the most generic, and 1 seems like a good choice.

Comment: I'd say $\epsilon=|L|$ would be more generic, then sequence is bounded by $|2L|$, but unfortunately it has a flaw when $L=0$, so we come back to $\epsilon=1$ eventually.

Comment: @zwim: Both good points.  I'm reminded of the proof that if a sequence has a positive limit, eventually all terms are positive.  There the choice of $\epsilon = L/2$ yields that eventually $L/2 < a_k < 3L/2$.

Answer (score 0):

It's perhaps psychological a bit. $1$ is not particularly small, and the choice makes the point that it's not important to choose a small $\epsilon$ -- any $\epsilon > 0$ works. So why not choose the first positive number that we can think of.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not why epsilon is chosen as 1. The question is "why not leave epsilon as epsilon" in the proof, instead of actually picking a value for it. Yes, it works for every epsilon, so we can just leave it as epsilon. Why not?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Exchange! Thank you for your effort in engaging with this community. In the [tour] it is explained that this site is primarily focused on gathering questions with their answers. This means we also try to keep things neat and tidy by moderating questions and answers. Currently, your answer does not add anything new to the already perfectly fine accepted answer. As explained in the [help](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers) section, duplicates of existing answers might get deleted. I'd suggest that you edit your answer if you have something valuable to add.